# Display modification type/target in question summary

Tags: feature-request, top-questions

Currently, on most, if not all SE sites display modified questions/questions with modified answers like this:

[image: Image showing that the text is displayed as only modified]

This implies that the question was modified, not an answer on the question, which in this case wouldn't be true.

I'd like to ask to display the type of edit that was made, such as "question modified" or "answer modified". This would clarify the reason why a question with no edits just showed up on the homepage as "modified".